# Ringtone volume keeps turning off

Tags: calls, ringtone

Using Samsung Galaxy A41 on Android 10, my ringtone volume is automatically resetting to 0 all the time - which means that I'm missing phone calls. I don't have any apps installed that should be doing this automatically.

What could be the cause and how can I debug this?

Comment: Have you checked whether "Do Not Disturb" is on or has its schedule too broad?

Comment: I do use "do not disturb" permanently because the notification noises from trivial things are annoying...